# Función para calcular y retornar números dentro de un array

Tags: javascript, array

No entiendo muy bien el ejercicio, se que tengo que poner un acumulador para que cuente cada punto, pero no se como hacer que después se sumen los puntos.
Gracias por su ayuda.

```
  function puntosDelEquipo(array) {
      // la funcion recibe un array con los resultados de los partidos del campeonato de futbol de un equipo
      // en este formato ["3:1", "2:2", "0:1", ...]
      //la funcion debe calcular y retornar cuantos puntos consiguio el equipo teniendo en cuenta:
      //que su resultado es el primero en cada string
      // un partido ganado suma 3 puntos, empate suma 1 punto, y perder 0!
      // Tu código aca:
    array.tostring().split(":").lenngth;
      var valor = 0;
      if(valor > 1 == 3)
  }
```

Comment: 1) Creas una variable para contar los pts. 2) Despúes un for para recorrer cada partido. 3) Dentro un split(":") para separar el marcadador. 4) Un if para ver cual es el mayor 5) Si el primero es el mayor sumas 3 y si son iguales sumas 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta es mi solución que te explico a continuación:

- Asigno una variable contador para ir sumando los puntos (3,1,0)
- Hago una iteración sobre el array para aplicar a cada elemento el método `split` cuyo separador sera **:** (los dos puntos).
- Luego solo quedar validar el resultado de tu equipo (team_a) vs el equipo contrario (team_b) utilizando el operador ternario

```js
function puntosDelEquipo(array){
    let counter = 0;
    array.forEach(result => {
      const resultSplit = result.split(":");
      const team_a = parseInt(resultSplit[0])
      const team_b = parseInt(resultSplit[1])
      const points = team_a > team_b ? 3 : team_a == team_b ? 1 : 0
      counter += points
    })
    return counter
}

puntosDelEquipo(["3:1", "2:2", "0:1", "6:5"])
```

Espero pueda ayudarte esta solución

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió un montón

Comment: Que bueno saber eso, si está respuesta  ayudo a resolver tu problema puedes marcar como aceptada dicha respuesta.